LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end even if \\ or \newline is not given
I am trying to submit an article to Acta Universitatis Sapientiae, Informatica journal. I downloaded both the "sample.tex" file and the "acta-inf.cls" class file. I have uploaded both in a project in overleaf along with a sample bibliography file "mybibfile.bib" and have set the compiler to "XeLateX" as recommended.  I am getting an error in compilation even without changing anything in the "sample.tex" file except for the citation keys. The error occurs in line 39 and the error message shown is  LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.  
This is happening only with the \printtwoauthors command and only one of the authors' names is displayed in the generated pdf preview completely. The error description says  "You have used a \ or \newline command where LaTeX was not expecting one."  I have not used either of the things mentioned in the description. Please help me rectify this error so that I can compile my article in the correct format and submit.
Note: I get the same error in both latex, pdflatex and lualatex compilers.
\documentclass{acta-inf}
\addbibresource{mybibfile.bib}

\usepackage{spverbatim}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}

\linenumbers
%% to be completed by the editor
\setDOI{10.2478/ausi-20yy-nnnn}
\received{DD MM 20yy}
\received[revised]{DD MM 20yy}
\received[accepted]{DD MM 20yy}
% \setvolume{10}
% \setissue{2}
% \setyear{2024}
% \setpages{123--456}
% \setcounter{page}{1}
%% to be completed by the editor 

\title{Preparing an Article using \LaTeX~for Acta Universitatis Sapientiae, Informatica}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

% Author 1
\newauthor{First Middle LASTNAME}
\affiliation{University of UniName\\ P.O. Box 1212, City, County, Country}
\email{email@theuniv.edu}
\orcid{1234-5678-9012}

% Author 2
\newauthor{\href{www.nstitution.org/~jimmyhomepage}{Jimmy GILL}}
\affiliation{Another Famous Institution}
\email{jimmy@institution.org}
% no orcid number
\printtwoauthors % Print both authors side by side

% Author 3
\newauthor{Kimmie D. WEXLER}
\affiliation{University of Somewhere\\ 70 Rockledge Dr., Brooklyn, New York, NY, 11225, USA}
\email{kim@anotheruniversity.edu}
\orcid{0000-1234-5678}


\printoneauthor % Print just one author

% Set the running head for authors and title
\short{F. M. Lastname et al.}{Preparing an Article}

% \oneauthor{Ben TROVATO}
% \email{trovato@corporation.com}
% \orcid{1234-5678-9012}
% \affiliation{Institute for Clarity in Documentation,\\ P.O. Box 1212, Dublin, Ohio, USA, 43017-6221}

% \oneauthor{Jim Bean}
% \email{jim@example.com}
% \orcid{1234-5678-8888}
% \affiliation{Institute for Clarity in Documentation,\\ P.O. Box 1212, Dublin, Ohio, USA, 43017-6221}

% \printauthorinfo


% \shortauthors{}



The command \printtwoauthors is defined in the class file as follows
% Command to print two authors side by side with conditional formatting
\newcommand{\printtwoauthors}{%
    \begin{center}
        % First Author
        \setcounter{authorCount}{\theauthorCount-1} % Decrement to get first author
        \noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{6.25cm}
            \begin{center}
                {\Large \csname authorname\theauthorCount\endcsname}\\
                \baselineskip=0.8\baselineskip
                \ifcsname affiliation\theauthorCount\endcsname
                    {\small \csname affiliation\theauthorCount\endcsname}\\
                \fi
                \ifcsname email\theauthorCount\endcsname
                    {\small \href{mailto:\csname email\theauthorCount\endcsname}{\emaillogo \hspace{1mm} \texttt{\csname email\theauthorCount\endcsname}}}\\
                \fi
                \ifcsname orcid\theauthorCount\endcsname
                    {\small \href{https://orcid.org/\csname orcid\theauthorCount\endcsname}{\orcidlogo \hspace{1mm} \texttt{\csname orcid\theauthorCount\endcsname}}}
                \fi
            \end{center}
        \end{minipage}\hspace*{0.5cm}%
        % Second Author
        \addtocounter{authorCount}{1} % Increment for the next author
        \begin{minipage}[t]{6.25cm}
            \begin{center}
                {\Large \csname authorname\theauthorCount\endcsname}\\
                \baselineskip=0.8\baselineskip
                \ifcsname affiliation\theauthorCount\endcsname
                    {\small \csname affiliation\theauthorCount\endcsname}\\
                \fi
                \ifcsname email\theauthorCount\endcsname
                    {\small \href{mailto:\csname email\theauthorCount\endcsname}{\emaillogo \hspace{1mm} \texttt{\csname email\theauthorCount\endcsname}}}\\
                \fi
                \ifcsname orcid\theauthorCount\endcsname
                    {\small \href{https://orcid.org/\csname orcid\theauthorCount\endcsname}{\orcidlogo \hspace{1mm} \texttt{\csname orcid\theauthorCount\endcsname}}}
                \fi
            \end{center}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{center}
}

Please help me out with this. The sample.tex file and the class file is available for everyone at
this submissions page

The question is how acta-inf implements \maketitle.  Typically, \maketitle prints both the title and author(s).

It's ok. I got the answer. This uses an older version of TeXLive in Overleaf. I was compiling in TeXLive version 2024 but this won't work unless it is TeXLive version 2023. So I'm closing the question now.
